# Use method controller in if statement while declaring route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use my show method in controller between if statement while declaring route:

```
Route::get('/leave', function() {
    if(Auth::user()->admin)
    {
        'uses' => 'TimeController@show'
    }
    else {
        return "not found";
    }
})->name('admin-time');
```

but the `uses` that I define it doesn't work! and I know it shouldn't works.

Comment: How about a separate route or a middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route:

```
Route::get('/leave', 'TimeController@show')->name('admin-time');
```

Controller:

```
public function show()
{
    if(!Auth::user()->admin)
    {
        return abort(404);
    }

    // your code.
}
```

> Remember: Do not use closure based routes. It prevents you from
>   `route:cache`.

Answer (score 1):

For authenticating like this you should use either a middleware:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

For example, protect the route by wrapping it in a custom middleware `auth:admin`:

```
Route::middleware('auth:admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/leave', ['uses' => 'TimeController@show'])->name('admin-time');
});
```

Or use a custom Request: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

For example, keep your route as:

`Route::get('/leave', ['uses' => 'TimeController@show'])->name('admin-time');`

In your `TimeController` your `show` method will have your custom `Request` that you can generate using `php artisan make:request MyCustomRequest`

```
public function show(MyCustomRequest $request) {
   ...
}
```

And in your `MyCustomRequest` you can add this to the `authorize()` method:

```
public function authorize()
{
    if (Auth::user()->admin) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```